# Brownian motion and inverse hitting time

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Given a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion $B$, we define the hitting time as
\begin{align*}
\tau_a:=\inf\{t\geq0 \, : \, B_t = a\},
\end{align*}
with $a \in \mathbb{R}$. From the continuity of the Brownian motion, we have that
\begin{align*}
B_{\tau_a}= a.
\end{align*}
Let $\tau_a^{-1}$ the right inverse of $\tau_a$. What can we say for $B_{\tau_a^{-1}}$ ?

We know that in law $\tau_a$ behaves as $1/2-$stable subordinator, then $\tau_a^{-1}$ in law is an inverse of an $1/2-$stable subordinator. I don't think we need it, since I have no independence between $B$ and $\tau_a$.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: you need to clarify what you mean by "inverse". Here $$\tau: \mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$$ . Because we have not defined $B_{-t}$, I suppose one route is to first restrict to $a>0$ i.e.  $$\tau: [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty).$$

Then this is indeed a strictly increasing function, so we can invert $$a=\tau^{-1}(y).$$

Comment: in "UNIQUENESS OF THE INVERSE FIRST-PASSAGE TIME PROBLEM AND THE SHAPEOF THE SHIRYAEV BOUNDARY" https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0040585X97T991155, there is interesting related discussion. Some of these techniques might be helpful for your particular question.